# Conditional Probability Multivariate Question

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, actuarial-science

Two life insurance policies, each with a death benefit of 10,000 and a one-time premium of 500, are sold to a couple, one for each person. The policies will expire at the end of the 10th year. The probability that only the wife will survive at least 10 years is 0.025, the probability that only the husband will survive at least 10 years is 0.01, and the probability that both of them will survive at least 10 years is 0.96. what is the expected excess of premiums over claims, given that the husband survives at least 10 years?

I understood that it was a conditional probability problem but I tried to solve it a different way and I'm not sure where my thinking is wrong. Here's what I tried:

X: wife survives 10 years, Y: husband survives 10 years

Since we are assuming the husband survives the 10 years, I disregarded the probability that only the wife survives the 10 years.

-(Premium for both policies) + (Death Benefit For One) * (Probability Only Husband Survives) + (No Death Benefit) * (Probability Husband and Wife Both Survive)
$$-1000 + 10000\times P(X' \cap Y) +0\times P(X \cap Y)$$

I have the solution so I know how to "correctly" solve it, I'm just confused about why this method I tried won't work.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: "The probability that only the wife will survive at least 10 years is 0.025, the probability that the husband will survive at least 10 years is 0.01, and the probability that both of them will survive at least 10 years is 0.96."  This is **contradictory**.  If you have two events $A$ and $B$, the probability of event $A$ occurring **can not be less** than the probability of both $A$ and $B$ simultaneously occurring.  The contradiction is that $0.01 < 0.96$.

Comment: If you intend that the probability of the husband **only** will survive at least 10 years (with the wife dying before the 10 years are up) equals $0.01$, then you need to edit your query to clarify this.  This presumes that you intend that the probability of neither surviving 10 years is $(1 - 0.01 - 0.025 - 0.96).$

Comment: There's no contradiction. It is possible that two events are more likely to occur simultaneously than on their own.

Comment: Edited to include "only the husband".

Answer (score 5):

You want the *conditional* expectation: $-1000+10000\,\mathsf P(X'\mid Y)+0\,\mathsf P(X\mid Y)$.

You are given $\mathsf P(X'\cap Y)=0.01$ and $\mathsf P(X\cap Y)=0.96$.

---

Recall the definition of conditional probability: $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X\mid Y)&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(X\cap Y)}{\mathsf P(Y)}\\[2ex]\mathsf P(X'\mid Y)&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(X'\cap Y)}{\mathsf P(Y)}\end{align}$$

Also recall the law of total probability : $$\mathsf P(Y)=\mathsf P(X\cap Y)+\mathsf P(X'\cap Y)$$

Comment: In what way is the conditional probability different from the intersection in this case in non math terms. Isn't "given that the wife dies" the same as "and the wife dies"?

Comment: Consider the toss of two fair coins.  The probability that the first is a head *when given* that the second is a head is $1/2$.  The probability that both are heads is $1/4$.

Comment: Conditional Probability is the measure of an event occurring under a restriction of possible outcomes. $\mathsf P(X\mid Y)$ is our measure of expectation that $X$ happens *should we be assured that* $Y$ will.

Comment: Joint Probability is the measure of two events simultaneously occurring (under no restriction).  $\mathsf P(X\cap Y)$ is our measure of expectation that $X$ and $Y$ will both happen ~~ *without any such assurance*.

Comment: The marginal probability $\mathsf P(Y)$ basically measures: "how *sure* are we that $Y$ will happen".  Hence $\mathsf P(X\cap Y)= \mathsf P(X\mid Y)\,\mathsf P(Y)$ .  The probability that $X$ and $Y$ happens equals the probability that $X$ happens when $Y$ does times the probability that $Y$ happens.

Comment: This was incredibly helpful. Thank you!